# Show SonarQube Dashboard in another portal

Tags: sonarqube

I have created dashboard with for different devops portal, now i want to show Sonar Dashboard in my dashboard. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Dashboards are dropped in SonarQube 6.2. For versions before that, try appending `?layout=false` to your dashboard URL.

Comment: Thanks @G. Ann.
I want to use multiple dashboard in iframe but it is not allowing me to do, I'm getting error related to X-Frame option. Is there any configuration available in Sonar to change that?